# Spurious dialogs "Project exists, overwrite from source control" when opening solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

Just recently, when I open a solution in VS2010, I get modal dialog boxes in the form

> "Project c:\XXXX\YYY\ZZZZ.csproj, which
>   you are getting from the source
>   control store, already exists. Would
>   you like to overwrite it with the
>   store version, or leave your local
>   copy?"

With the options **Overwrite**, **Overwrite All**, **Leave** and **Help**. I get one of these dialog boxes per project in the solution, unless I click **Overwrite All**. Either of the Overwrite options appears to do a get for every file in the project(s), which as you can imagine is time consuming for a large solution. And clicking **Leave** for every project in a large solution is also time consuming.

The obvious cause is the option **Source Control** -> **Environment** -> **Get everything when a solution or project is opened**, however this is not turned on. I tried turning the option on and then off again, in case something was wrong with the option setting, but this did not solve the issue.

I've tried a few searches for this issue, but couldn't find anyone else suffering it.

Any help solving this would be appreciated.

I've also asked this [question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/193812/spurious-dialogs-project-exists-overwrite-from-source-control-when-opening-sol)

Comment: This behaviour has gone away for me, as mysteriously as it started. May as well leave it open, in case someone finds an answer, for those unlucky enough to encounter this odd behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your Visual Studio Cache Settings and then try again.

Comment: I've mark you up for this suggestion, but I'm no longer suffering the issue, so I don't know if this is the correct answer, unfortunately. If anyone leaves a comment saying this worked for them, I'll mark your answer correct. Thanks anyhow though!

Comment: I just had the same problem. I cleared the cache located on my Win7 machine at C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache, but this didn't fix the problem. I then re-started VS2010 and the problem was gone. So the solution was either just restarting VS2010, or clearing the cache and restarting VS2010. FWIW, I am leaning towards just re-starting VS2010 as I had been messing around with my TFS workspace settings.

Comment: Accepted the answer - in the absence of being able to reproduce the issue, this is as good as it gets :-)